# Article automation solutions for Drupal?

Tags: 6

Does anyone know of any article automation services that allows easy creation of content into Drupal 6?

Something like [Article Marketing Automation](http://www.articlemarketingautomation.com) would be great if their promised integration worked as advertised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the type of content you want to create.

If you're looking for test content then [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) will create dummy content for your site.

If you're looking for more spam (not judging) content then you'd have to go down the custom route. Here's a sample workflow:

1. Use [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) to aggregate a few different sites to a content type that isn't published.
2. Use [Open Calais](http://drupal.org/project/opencalais) to scan the content and auto create taxonomies.
3. Use a custom module to create new nodes based on a term, this would bring in x amount of automatically scraped nodes aggregate them into one, you can then publish the newly created node.

I don't agree with the outcome but I find it an interesting challenge coming up with a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Random content isn't the requirement. I don't think there is an answer, but was wondering if there were any sites that produce *genuine* content. Client thinks there are content writers that publish their content to be consumed but I'm not convinced.

Comment: Oh and +1 for Open Calais, I didn't know about that.

Comment: What your client probably needs is a copy writer to write the content for them, or find a decent source of white papers on the subject. Not really a suitable question for Drupal Stackexchange.